# avoiding for loops in F#

Tags: for-loop, f#, functional-programming

I have a list of strings and numbers like the following

```
let stringsAndNums = [("aa-",20); ("b1",20); ("aa",10); ("b12",10); ("+aa-",30)]
```

I need to partition the list into groups of strings that are included one in another.

For each of the above groups I have to find the minimum and maximum value.

This is what I have tried to do: it is working, but I don't think it is idiomatic F# and I guess I should avoid the for loops.

```
for tup in stringsAndNums do
    let subject, value = tup
    let related = 
        stringsAndNums |> List.filter( 
            fun o -> 
                       let osubject, ovalue = o; 
                       osubject.Contains(subject) || subject.Contains(osubject);
             )

    let relvalues = related |> List.map(fun o -> 
                                  let osubject, ovalue = o; 
                                  ovalue
                       )  
    let min = (relvalues |> List.min)
    let max = (relvalues |> List.max) 
    printfn "%A" (subject, value, min, max, (max - min))
```

Also, how can I define a function returning the list of tuple results instead of printing them?

### Desired output.

The results I'm getting look fine

```
("aa-", 20, 10, 30, 20)
("b1", 20, 10, 20, 10)
("aa", 10, 10, 30, 20)
("b12", 10, 10, 20, 10)
("+aa-", 30, 10, 30, 20)
```

In fact the two groups in this case are formed by

1. `+aa-` with value 30,`aa` with value 10,`aa-` with value 20, so max is 30 and min is 10
2. `b1` with value 20,`b12` with value 10

### My solution

What I've now managed to do: there is no longer a for-loop now, but is this code truly functional?

```
let results =
   stringsAndNums |> List.map(fun tup ->

//for tup in stringsAndNums do
    let subject, value = tup
    let related = 
        stringsAndNums |> List.filter( 
            fun o -> 
                       let osubject, ovalue = o; 
                       osubject.Contains(subject) || subject.Contains(osubject);
             )
    //for reltup in related do
    let relvalues = related |> List.map(fun o -> 
                                  let osubject, ovalue = o; 
                                  ovalue
                       )  
    let min = (relvalues |> List.min)
    let max = (relvalues |> List.max) 
    printfn "%A" (subject, value, min, max, (max - min))
)

for result in results do
    printf "%A" result
```

Comment: Could you show what your desired output would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I dont grasp what you are trying to accomplish my solution is just a bit of clean up

```
let stringsAndNums = [("aa-",20); ("b1",20); ("aa",10); ("b12",10); ("+aa-",30)]
let results =
    let split (subject, value) = 
        let related =
            //first I created a named function for the filter expression
            let filtering (osubject:string, _) = osubject.Contains(subject) || subject.Contains(osubject) 
            stringsAndNums |> List.filter filtering 
        //accessing the 2 first items of a tuple can be done via fst, snd 
        let relvalues = related |> List.map snd 
        let min = (relvalues |> List.min)
        let max = (relvalues |> List.max) 
        //I assume you wanted to return that tuple so away with the printf
        (subject, value, min, max, (max - min))

    stringsAndNums |> List.map split

for result in results do
    //and lastly use printfn (n-for newline) so the printing is nicer
    printfn "%A" result
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would write it.

```
let subjectValues = [("aa-",20); ("b1",20); ("aa",10); ("b12",10); ("+aa-",30)]

let getRelated (subject, value) =
    let relValues = 
        subjectValues
        |> List.choose (fun (s, v) ->
            if s.Contains(subject) || subject.Contains(s)
            then Some v
            else None)

    let min = relValues |> List.min
    let max = relValues |> List.max

    (subject, value, min, max, (max - min))

let results = subjectValues |> List.map getRelated

printfn "%A" results
```

- It's not functional for the `List.map` function to return `unit` (something like `void`). It was producing a printing side-effect instead of a value.
- Tuple pattern matching can be done directly in the function parameter, rather than in a separate `let`.
- I generally try to write the function that acts on a single item, and then use it with a List.map if needed, as I find this cleaner and more flexible.
- I replaced `List.map ... List.filter` with `List.choose` which just does both in one step. This had the effect of removing an intermediate hard-to-name `let` value.
- I renamed some values to give them more meaning, I hope.